# `bin/rails server` opening a text file instead of running a local server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Starting a rails tutorial: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.
Followed every step but when I get to running the command `bin/rails server` the text file below opens instead of running a server. How do I get this command to run the server instead?

```
    #!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
    APP_PATH = File.expand_path("../config/application", __dir__)
    require_relative "../config/boot"
    require "rails/commands"
```

Comment: Have you tried tip from that tutorial?
```
If you are using Windows, you have to pass the scripts under the bin folder directly to the Ruby interpreter e.g. ruby bin\rails server.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `rails server` or `rails s` instead, which is a more idiomatic way to run the Rails server.

Comment: Wow this was all that was needed. Thank you it worked.

Comment: glad to help and welcome to the Rails community!